# How to run vim commands/scripts from project root?

Tags: vim, ctags

I have a multitude of commands I'd like to run not in the current directory, but in the project root directory. i.e. going up directories until I reach some indication of a root, like .git directory for example.

For example running vimgrep -r (recursive) on all my project, or running tags generation recursively on whole project.

How do I get that path? The only close indication I found is this:set tags=./tags;~/Projects
But that just saves the string as it is into tags. Assigning something similar but for the use case described, gets me the string verbatim.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: It is generally recommended to start Vim in your project root and not change the working directory.

Comment: That's an interesting proposition, albeit less flexible.
Could you elaborate on some reasons why it isn't recommended to change the working directory?

Comment: Well… why do you keep changing your working directory? The working directory is your "project": that's where you build, where you run your tests, where your VCS directory exists, where you put your `tags` file, where you can reach every file in your project…

Comment: ctrlp handles being able to reach every file in my project. Changing the working directory automatically depending on the current buffer gives me two things that jump to my mind:  
**1**. when creating a new file through :e I know where it will be placed without having to mentally remind myself where I opened in gvim (which isn't always in some project root).  
**2**. when working on more than one project in the same vim with split windows There's definitely merit to what you say. It's just less flexible to refer to my vim working directory as the project working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the idea of "changing the working directory" or distinguishing between "working directory and project root", because almost no tool is prepared to properly handle those concepts.

The only tools that do (e.g. git) are those that don't care about the current directory to begin with.

Otherwise, it's madness to try to get everything working without bad side effects. "Working directory" is a concept too fundamental to even attempt to change within a running program.

The best approach is open a new Vim sessions inside directories where you want to do "local" things - and switch back to the "project" session to run project commands. Vim will protect you from accidentally overwriting changes in another session.

The alternative is to wrap commands in shells so they can have their "own" working directories, e.g.:

```
:!cd ../../..; ctags -R
```

(Which would allow you to regenerate tags file for the project, and not just the current dir)

or:

```
:!cd ../../..; grep -r foo **/*
```

But any output with file names would be relative to that root directory, and not the current one.

So you may prefer to do:

```
:!cd ../../..; vim
```

which creates a new Vim session within the current one, but in the context of the root directory.

Or, you may prefer the reverse (assuming Vim is running *in* the project root):

```
:!cd $(dirname %); vim
```

Which lets you work in the directory of the current file - and you'd have to exit to the main session to run project-wide tools again.

So instead of "changing" directories, you're "changing vim sessions" (either by having 2 sessions or "nesting" one in another like above).

Comment: That last suggestion is pretty simple so I'll go with that.
Combining with what I found on Vim tips:
cabbr <expr> %% expand('%:p:h')
typing %%/ expands it to the directory of the file I'm editing

Comment: Be careful with that abbreviation it will expand in unlikely places like when you are searching, e.g. `/%%`. You might be off with a mapping: `cnoremap <c-r><c-d> <c-r>=expand('%:p:h')<cr>`

Answer (score 2):

I use a [local_vimrc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc) plugin to set project related variables. Then, I use (/write) plugins that rely on (buffer/project)-local variables to do stuff. (Unfortunately, most plugin out there rely of global variables which is not the best choice to specialize their behaviour to the current project in multi-projects sessions)

Regarding ctags generation, in use [lh-tags](http://lh-vim.googlecode.com/svn/tags/trunk/lh-tags-addon-info.txt) that requires a [few variables to be set](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/mu-template/trunk/after/template/vim/internals/vim-rc-local-ccpp.template#63).

Regarding grepping, as other, I usually start from the current directory which is often the root directory of my project. But you could also easily have a plugin/command that would run something like:

```
exe "vimgrep -r ".pattern." ".
  \ map(file_extensions, 
  \     string(lh#option#get('project_root_directory').'/**').'v:val')
```

EDIT:

If you don't want other configuration files, and if the `.git/` directory is enough to identify your project root directory, then, you can have this kind of function to get your project root directory:

```
function! ProjectRootDirectory()
   return fnamemodify(finddir('.git', '.;'), ':h')
endfunction
```

Then when you'll run ctags, you'll have to execute ctags from the result of this vim function. I don't know which plugin you use to run ctags, at this moment. My lh-tags doesn't support functions through its configuration variables. It can easily been added if need be.
However, I don't see a simple way to configure `&tags` once from the `.vimrc` in order to configure this setting on a per project basis.

Comment: Thanks Luc, that will really solve the problem.
However that will solve more than I bargained for at the expense of needing another file per project.
While not a big price to pay, as long as all I need now is just being able to go up directories, I prefer a simple command and/or script I can run before things like vimgrep and/or tags generation.

Comment: There is a way to obtain the project root directory if there is a file or directory that marks it. This root directory can then be computed dynamically and exploited by plugins. However, I see to adapt `&tags` on the fly to exploit the detected root directory -- other than local_vimrc plugins.  
I've edit my message with more details on the subject.

Comment: That is interesting. I'm not too familiar with the limitations of where I can execute vimscript though. I'll have to investigate that.

Answer (score 2):

I personally like to keep it simple and have my current directory be my project root. I can use `%` to represent the current file in commands, e.g. `:!git add %`. Along with `%` you can use filename modifiers, e.g. `:e %:h/foo.txt`. See `:h filename-modifiers`.

However you mentioned that you use [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) and you like the way it changes the current directory. This means you need to be a bit more creative.

Here is what I would recommend:

- Update your tags via git hooks. See [Effortless Ctags with Git](http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html)
- If your tags are in `.git/tags` [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) will automatically setup these tags for you.
- Use `:Ggrep` which uses `git grep` so it already know about your project root directory and as a bonus is much faster than `:vimgrep`.
- Running arbitrary commands from the root is trickier. I use [projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) to manage my projects. Projectionist provides the command, `:ProjectDo`, which does exactly what you want.

**Now a word of caution**: Vim has no understanding of a "project". The closest thing to is `'exrc'` option (See `:h 'exrc'`) which is pretty lame.

Comment: That is creative! It'll take me a while before I can sit down and adopt all these tools though. Thanks for bringing these tools to my awareness!

Comment: I highly recommend using [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) if you are using git. [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) has a set of screencast on how to use fugitive: [The Fugitive Series - a retrospective](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/)

Comment: Thanks Peter! Fugitive really is awesome!